# Большая задержка в вводе текст SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Всем привет, в моём проекте sfml используется ввод текста в текстовое поле. По умолчанию такой функции нет в sfml, но я поискал в интернете и нашёл способ (код ниже). Вообщем спрашивал у людей, которые использовали тот же способ - у них все нормально, а у меня текст появляется с очень большой задержкой, приходится выжимать кнопку несколько секунд чтобы текст появился.

Вот код на c++ & sfml:

```
    sf::Event event;

    while (this->window->pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered)
        {
            if (event.text.unicode < 128)

            {
                if (event.text.unicode == 13) // return key
                {
                    // finished entering name
                }
                else if (event.text.unicode == 8) { // backspace
                    if (name.size() > 0) name.resize(name.size() - 1);
                }
                else {
                    name += static_cast<char>(event.text.unicode);
                }
                text.setString(name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Если кто то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, напишите как ее решили. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: надо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, непонятно, что значит `появляется с очень большой задержкой`, где и как он появляется?

Comment: Смысле непонятно, я же написал ввод текста в sfml, появляется на экране, по нажатию клавишы на клавиатуре значение этой клавиши появляется на мониторе в видо текста sfml. Только с очень большой задержкой.

Comment: Так может в обновлении экрана большая задержка?

Comment: @SemyonDyachenko, что такое `text`? `sf::Text`? Каким образом он выводится на экран? Приведите полный текст программы.

Comment: Pavel Gridin, в чем смысл мне сейчас тратить время отвечать вам на вопрос, если я сделал пометку что sfml, чтобы сюда заходили люди имеющие дело с этой библиотекой, а о чем говорить если вы меня спрашиваете что такое sf::Text, и да , это не программа а игра , 6 тысяч строк кода , весь код привести? конкретно в данной случае вывода текста на экран - это полный код.

Comment: @SemyonDyachenko, вам даже нет смысла тратить время на вопросы, раз вы не читаете ответы

Comment: @PavelGridin, во-первых у меня тоже есть дела.Во-вторых я изначально понимал ,что мало вероятно что мне дадут ответ на этот вопрос , потому что облазив интернет похожих запросов я не находил, ну и в третьих , читать ответы по типу "что такое sf::Text" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, я так обновление сделал в цикле, и всё летает, так что проблема как говорилось выше в моменте отображения текста на экран.

```
while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();

        if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered)
        {
            if (event.text.unicode < 128)

            {
                if (event.text.unicode == 13) // return key
                {
                    // finished entering name
                }
                else if (event.text.unicode == 8) { // backspace
                    if (name.size() > 0) {
                        name.resize(name.size() - 1);
                        text.setString(name);
                        
                        
                    }
                }
                else {
                    name += static_cast<char>(event.text.unicode);
                }
                text.setString(name);
                text.setPosition(20, 100);
            }
        }
        
    }
    window.clear();
    window.draw(text);
    window.display();
}
```